# Is it possible to persist my ECS container storage using S3?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am hosting my wordpress site using `ECS`

**How i persist my data right now**

I have mounted an `EFS` on `var/www/html` so all my wordpress configurations,uploads etc persist

**Problem**

`EFS` is slow compared to S3 and my site is having latency issues

**Desired outcome**

Is it possible to store my `var/www/html` from inside my `docker` container in an `ECS` instance such that it stores `var/www/html` on `S3`?

So i can use S3 to access my wordpress site which is lot faster than `EFS`

Comment: I suppose your configuration is somewhat close to the one described in this article? https://blog.andreev.it/?p=4417

Comment: On a high level yes,But i don't have an elastic load balancer right now... also i did not have to setup user data to mount EFS as AWS has launched EFS mounting directly on container via task definition so i directly mounted it and it was working :)

Comment: Following this conversation. EFS is found to be not suitable for web workload ( with many small files )
Personally I install Wordpress plugins to move image / attachment onto S3. This approach does not help with static wordpress assets though and time to first byte will still be high for these

Comment: Lets assume i did install the required plugin and was able to move my files to S3 , The tricky part is making the container use files from S3 instead of `var/www/html` directory in the filesystem.. i am looking for a way if any to mount my s3 bucket inside `var/www/html` somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we configure WP on ECS so files persist, while maintaining performance:

The key is to separate the WordPress software files from the media uploads folder.

WordPress, by default, will store the uploaded files in the `wp-content/uploads` folder. WordPress allows you to customize the upload folder destination.

1. Install the WP system files into `/var/www`.
2. Mount an ECS file system on `/var/files`.
3. Configure WordPress to upload media files to that folder. Open the WordPress `wp-config.php` file, and add the following code after `require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-settings.php');` declaration: `define('UPLOADS', '/var/files');`.

This is the recommended configuration for serving php files from the local filesystem while moving media files to persistent storage. EFS is preferred to S3 because it can be easily mounted as a file system.

This will also work well if you scale to more than one server. It will also make software deployments and upgrades easier, as software and media files will not be co-mingled.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. You could use the LustreFS filesystem with a bucket behind it- this would expose a filesystem on your end that is a bit more high performance than EFS. You could also use a Storage Gateway but that gets a bit more complicated.

Once you have your files in a bucket you should configure Wordpress to serve them from that bucket- setup the bucket for static file serving, pop a domain on it, and then tweak your wordpress config so static files are served from that domain. If you really want high performance you can put CloudFront in front of that as well so your files are served from local caches.

Comment: Storage Gateway is on on-premise to cloud data storage service. How would you see that working in this use case?

Comment: Storage Gateway is *not* just on premise. AWS also supplies AMIs for the gateway on their [Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Amazon-Web-Services-AWS-Storage-Gateway/B00AZ4Q6MM).

Comment: Yes. But it connects to on premise component always. It's part of a hybrid Cloud solution. How exactly would you use it in this case?